# Where did the $i$ go in the second order differential equation solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

Let $a\ddot{y}+b\dot{y}+cy=0$ such that $b^2-4ac<0$, we then have a solution of the form

$y=e^{\alpha t}(A\cos(\beta t)+B\sin(\beta t))$

Where $\alpha$ is the real part, and $\beta$ the absolute value of the imaginary part of the solutions of the following polynomial equation:

$ax^2+bx+c=0$

However, when I try to prove this general solution, I find

$y=Ae^{(\alpha+i\beta)t}+Be^{(\alpha-i\beta)t}$

$y=e^{\alpha t}(Ae^{i\beta t}+Be^{-i\beta t})$

$y=e^{\alpha t}(A(\cos(\beta t)+i\sin(\beta t))+B(\cos(-\beta t)+i\sin(-\beta t)))$

$y=e^{\alpha t}((A+B)\cos(\beta t)+i(A-B)\sin(\beta t))$

Could anyone please explain to me how we get rid of the $i$ to find the general solution?

Comment: How did your attempt to prove the general solution yield the second expression for $y$?

Comment: Note that the general solution admits constants $A, B\in\mathbb C$.

Comment: But isn't y supposed to be real?

Comment: It doesn't have to be.

Comment: Note that the $t$ is missing in the beginning of your derivation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the constants $A, B$ that you write in the first version of $y=\ldots$ are *not* the same that you use in your derivation.

Renaming the second pair to $A\to C$ and $B\to D$, your proof would start out with $y(t) = Ce^{t(\alpha + i \beta)} + D e^{t(\alpha-i\beta)}$. Now we make the following observations:

- If $C,D\in\mathbb R$, then $y(t)\notin\mathbb R$ in general, because you always have the term $i(C-D) \sin(\beta t)$, which is nonzero whenever $C\neq D$.
- If you want to reproduce the original expression, you would have to match the coefficients:
  $$A = C+D,\quad B = i(C-D),$$
  and you can solve this for $C,D$ if you want.

Point is, $A,B$ and $C,D$ may be complex, and won't be real simultaneously. Both formulations of the general solution that you mention are equivalent. Since your ansatz using $e^{\alpha + i \beta}$ will carry you out of the real numbers, you can't expect every solution to be real - you have to choose the coefficients accordingly to achieve that.

Comment: What ansatz would one need to use to always get real solutions?

Comment: Use this directly: $y=e^{\alpha t}(A\sin\beta t + B\cos\beta t)$, and plug it in your ODE to see that it satisfies it.